# How to convert second select statement result to CSV String in main select statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert second select statement result to CSV String in main select statement ?

assume following SQL statement:

```
SELECT A1,A2, (SELECT aCol FROM Table2) as A3
FROM Table1
```

Now, I want to convert result of **SELECT aCol FROM Table2** to CSV string that show at A3 field.
such as :

```
A1Value | A2Value | A3Value1, A3Value2, A3Value3
```

thanks.

---

**Update :**

[Solution for MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aware that without correlation, you'll get the same comma separated list for every row returned?

### For MySQL

Use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT t.a1,
            t.a2,
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.acol)
                FROM TABLE_2 t2) AS A3
   FROM TABLE_1 t
```

### Assuming SQL Server 2005+

Use:

```
SELECT t.a1,
            t.a2,
            STUFF(ISNULL(SELECT ', '+x.acol                
                                   FROM TABLE_2 x 
                            GROUP BY x.acol             
                              FOR XML PATH ('')),''),1,2,'')
  FROM TABLE_1 t
```

Comment: @Behrouz Mohamadi: Group based string concatenation in Oracle isn't as clean SQL Server (which is a hack) or MySQL - [this article}(http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) gives a good rundown of the options.